# Problem when specifying Excel file in Execute Office Scripts action

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

I'm trying to run a flow with Office Scripts on Excel file red from Sharepoint document library.

Office Script works perfectly when I manually execute it on statically selected Excel file.

However, when I set a dynamic file value from sharepoint library, I get 404 error such:

"**The script could not be executed. Please try again. The script was unable to create a connection with Excel. Please try again**"

(error message translated from italian, sorry...).

Flow extract follows:

[image]

I've tried `Name`, `DisplayName`, `Id` and more, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for any help!

PS. my flow works with no errors when I remove "Execute script" action... :smirking_face:

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution inserting "Get file properties" action between "create file" and "Run script"

[image: complete working flow]

I hope people can find it useful...